# Next.js - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I use Next.js and Next-auth for my project.

I'm building a Sidebar component where I want to show a list of items from a user.

So I'm getting the session with useSession.

When I log the session like so...

```js
export default function Sidebar() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  console.log(session);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

...I get an object including the user object.

But when I try to log the user like so...

```js
export default function Sidebar() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  console.log(session.user);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Any idea what's the problem here?

Thanks a lot,
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

As useSession is a hook, it will make data available asynchronously. Hence, you need to check if session is not undefined before logging it/ using it.

```
console.log(session?.user);
```

or

```
if(session) {
  console.log(session.user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the deconstruction of the object.
And it's recommended you check if it's not null, just like Rameez said.
Try this:

```
const { data, status } = useSession();

if(data.session.user){
    console.log(data.session.user);
}

return (
    ...
);
```